# Verifying sale of app on IOS on web server

Tags: ios, app-store

I am currently building an App that will be linked to a web site. Is there a way to verify the purchase of an IOS application from the app store?

This will link to the user account on the web site to unlock additional features in the web site. I have found extensive topics on the validation of receipts for in-app purchases but this would be validating the receipt for the sale of the app itself? I don't really want to have a free app with the additional content as an in-app purchase and would prefer to validate from the sale of the app itself.

Ideally this would need to be a secure method that cannot be replicated by a user as it will access expensive high level content.

Comment: Receipt validation can be used to verify the purchase of the app in addition to verifying in-app purchases.